# Error configuring dynamic methods for plugin [logging:1.3.7]: Cannot add new method [getLog]

Tags: logging, grails, grails-plugin

grails 1.3.7
when startup,get error below:

> Running Grails application..
>   2011-04-22 09:38:17,828 [main] ERROR
>   plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager  -
>   Error configuring dynamic methods for
>   plugin [logging:1.3.7]: Cannot add new
>   method [getLog] for arguments [[]]. It
>   already exists!
>   groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException:
>   Cannot add new method [getLog] for
>   arguments [[]]. It already exists!    at
>   org.grails.tomcat.TomcatServer.start(TomcatServer.groovy:212)
>     at
>   grails.web.container.EmbeddableServer$start.call(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5_closure12.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:158)
>     at
>   _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5_closure12.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy)
>     at
>   _GrailsSettings_groovy$_run_closure10.doCall(_GrailsSettings_groovy:280)
>     at
>   _GrailsSettings_groovy$_run_closure10.call(_GrailsSettings_groovy)
>     at
>   _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:149)
>     at
>   _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5.call(_GrailsRun_groovy)
>     at
>   _GrailsRun_groovy.runInline(_GrailsRun_groovy:116)
>     at
>   _GrailsRun_groovy.this$4$runInline(_GrailsRun_groovy)
>     at
>   _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure1.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:59)  at
>   RunApp$_run_closure1.doCall(RunApp.groovy:33)     at
>   gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:381)
>     at
>   gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)
>     at
>   gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)  at
>   gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)
>     at
>   gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)
>     at
>   gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners.callCurrent(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)
>     at
>   gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)
>     at
>   gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)
>     at
>   gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590)
>     at
>   gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:589)

Comment: are you updating a project to a new version of Grails? A more detailed description  would be more helpful.

Comment: no,just a new project of grails1.3.7

Comment: not an answer, but you can try "grails clean" and re-run it again. You may want to create a new blank project, and try to run it.

Comment: @Hoàng Long: i try clean and re-run, the same error warning. new blank project work fine... i will check it deep later..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that you've provided very little contextual information, it's very difficult to provide any assistance. My best guess is that the logging plugin is trying to add a `log` property or a `getLog()` method to one of your classes (most likely a controller, service, or domain), but you've already declared this property/method in the same class.

Comment: "at org.grails.tomcat.TomcatServer.start(TomcatServer.groovy:212)"  -- i think maybe it's bug of tomcat plugin again... i dont declare any getLog method

Comment: fixed..one of my domain :static hasMany = [forward:Forward,log:OperLog]